# Docker-compose up springboot + postgres Connection refused

Tags: java, postgresql, docker

I create an sample java project with springboot data and postgres. I started to make my docker-compose but i can't link my database to my application...

I have this error

```
web_1  | org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5438 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

On my application ressource

```
server:
  port: 4000

spring:
  datasource:
    platform: postgres
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5438/acronym
    username: acronym
    password: acronym1234
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    database: POSTGRESQL
    show-sql: true
    generate-ddl: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
```

and my docker compose file

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  web:
    image: acronym:latest
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    networks:
      - webnet
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    restart: always
    environment:
     - POSTGRES_USER=acronym
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=acronym1234
     - POSTGRES_DB=acronym
      -PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    volumes:
         - /var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5438:5432'
volumes:
    db:
networks:
    webnet:
```

I saw a lot of topic and the solution is to replace localhost to db but that doesn't work

How can i link my database to my app with docker-compose ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `jdbc:postgresql://db:5438/acronym` as connection url.

The service is exposed under its name by default (in that case `db`).

Comment: Thx you to reply ! Yes I tried to replace localhost to db on my applocation resource, I have the same issue :(

Comment: Ok i try again with db and the port 5432 ...and it work !! THX YOU

Comment: You mapped the ports, inside the docker network (webnet) it is available under the port 5438 and on the localhost over 5432.
`ports:
      - '5438:5432'`
You could use the same port to avoid confusion => `ports: - '5438:5438'`